# Electron App Not Starting after I build it

Tags: deployment, build, package, electron, electron-packager

I have installed the electron-packager npm module globally and run npm run build to build my application.

When I do this, the app seems to build properly and it outputs an application (see picture). However, the date/time on the application is from over a month ago. Furthermore, when I open the application, it simply presents a blank screen.

Below, please find my package.json and accompanying pictures.

```
{
  "name": "turtlecreeklane",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Tanner Houghton <houta483@uchicago.edu>",
  "description": "An electron-vue project",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "./dist/electron/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "electron-packager . TCL",
    "build:dir": "node .electron-vue/build.js && electron-builder --dir",
    "build:clean": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=clean node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "build:web": "cross-env BUILD_TARGET=web node .electron-vue/build.js",
    "dev": "./start_backend.sh& node .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
    "pack": "npm run pack:main && npm run pack:renderer",
    "pack:main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.main.config.js",
    "pack:renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --config .electron-vue/webpack.renderer.config.js",
    "postinstall": ""
  },
  "build": {
    "productName": "turtlecreeklane",
    "appId": "com.example.yourapp",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/electron/**/*"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icons/Icon-48"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icons/icon.ico"
    },
    "linux": {
      "icon": "build/icons"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "ejs": "^3.0.2",
    "electron-unhandled": "^3.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pillow": "0.0.9",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vuex": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "cfonts": "^2.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.6",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron": "^2.0.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.19.2",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.0",
    "multispinner": "^0.2.1",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.4",
    "vue-loader": "^15.2.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

[Picture showing that the project seems to be built but the date if for over a month ago...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfbbP.png)

[Picture showing that the app looks blank after it is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJJfB.png)

Thanks,
Tanner

Comment: may be an issue with electron-packager, try electron-builder https://www.electron.build

Comment: working well at your dev mode but not showing anything at prod mode means, it lost the loading url. you should make sure the index.html is placed in proper location.

Comment: As well, recommend to use builder than packager.

Comment: You could also enable the devtools also to see if thare are some errors shown